# Quartz Trigger new thread?

Tags: java, triggers, quartz-scheduler

Does a quartz scheduler create a new thread for each of the triggers or only a single thread which takes care of all the threads ?

Answer (score 2):

Quartz uses a configurable thread pool to execute the scheduled tasks. So threads should be recycled between the job executions. How many threads there are in parallel can be configured as is described here:
http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/configuration/ConfigThreadPool

As you can give implementations to the ThreadPool interface yourself, you can, however, deviate and generate a "ThreadPool" that does no pooling at all. (The Interface to implement is described here: http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/org/quartz/spi/ThreadPool.html)